# local storage not defined why?

Tags: javascript, storage, submit, local, form-submit

why when I try to submit the form is it saying local storage not defined.

```js
let info = [];

const addInfo = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  let formInfo = {
    cardNumber: document.getElementById('cardNumber').value,
    creditExpires: document.getElementById('creditExpires').value,
    creditCvc: document.getElementById('creditCvc').value,
    firstName: document.getElementById('firstName').value,
    lastName: document.getElementById('lastName').value,
    emailaddress: document.getElementById('emailAddress').value,
    phoneNumber: document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value,
    country: document.getElementById('country').value,
    streetAddress: document.getElementById('streetAddress').value,
    city: document.getElementById('city').value,
    state: document.getElementById('state').value,
    zipcode: document.getElementById('zipcode').value,
    comments: document.getElementById('comments').value

  }
  info.push[formInfo];
  document.forms[0].reset();
  localstorage.info = JSON.stringify(info);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('submitDonation').addEventListener('click', addInfo);
});
```

Comment: It's `localStorage` not `localstorage`. JS is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

It is "localStorage" not "localstorage" , JavaScript Variables are case-sensitive.
There is a convention for naming variable - lowerCamelCase.
Most variables are named that way, Variables can't have whitespaces (Spaces, Horizontal tabs, ....,.) So the convention is to concatenate the names using by keeping the first word of the variable small & The First Letter of each Successive World is Capitalised.

Like for example :

1. the local storage object is named : localStorage.
2. the session storage object is named : sessionStorage.
3. Or for that matter even methods for DOM manipulations like : getElementById(), getElementByClassName, getElementByTagName.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to capitalize the s in storage..
change `localstorage` to `localStorage`